# Let-bind diplayed windows and their size/posizion

Tags: window, window-configuration

Can I let-bind diplayed windows and their size/posizion? Is there a variable that stores these infos?

I need to run a script that will change the diplayed windows, opening some help temp buffers. At the end of the script I'd like to restore the starting layout (displayed windows and their size/posizion).

**Edit.** Finally I found that `current-frame-configuration`/`set-frame-configuration` is what I need,

Comment: See the section of the manual describing `set-window-configuration`, `current-window-configuration`, etc.:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html  See also the section of the manual describing saving window configurations to the register:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Configuration-Registers.html  Odds are that there are similar and perhaps even duplicate threads regarding these issues ..., but I haven't done any Googling in that regard.

Comment: What @lawlist said. And yes, you can let-bind a variable whose value is a window config.

Comment: @lawlist I googled and searched for this info but I was not able to find it. I still think that the manual lacks of pratical examples. But that's my opinion and maybe this is not hte case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html), browse through the top level table of content. You're interested in windows, so go to the [chapter on windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Windows.html#Windows). Browse through its table of contents until you find “Saving and restoring the state of the screen”, which is the section [window configurations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html#Window-Configurations). Now you know how Emacs calls what you're looking for and you know what functions are available.

- [`(current-window-configuration)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html#index-current_002dwindow_002dconfiguration) is the information about displayed windows that you can let-bind.
- [`set-window-configuration`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Csaonfigurations.html#index-set_002dwindow_002dconfiguration) lets you restore the saved window configuration.
- [`save-window-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html#index-save_002dwindow_002dexcursion) packages the functions above to run some code and restore the original window configuration (whether the code terminates successfully or errors out).

```
(save-window-excursion
  ;; your code goes here
  )
```

Furthermore, as noted in the documentation, there's a related macro [`save-selected-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Selecting-Windows.html#index-save_002dselected_002dwindow) with similar usage but which does something slightly different.

```
(save-selected-window
  ;; your code goes here
  )
```

`save-window-excursion` saves the exact window arrangement (sizes, positions, displayed buffer) of the current frame only. `save-selected-window` does not save window arrangements, but remembers which window is selected in each frame. Given what you want to do, which involves displaying (and therefore making room for) extra windows, I think `save-window-excursion` is the right one.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I was sure I searched for the windows stuff in the manual. Anyway, `save.window-escursion` is what I was searching for.

Comment: Finally I found that `current-frame-configuration`/`set-frame-configuration` is what I need,